# React - Dividing a Large Form into Multiple Components

Tags: reactjs, forms, architecture

I have a large form consisting of 30-40 fields.

The form is logically and visually divided into parts. For example: "address details" "credit card details". I would like to divide it into multiple React components.

In my form, changes by user in some parts often cause other parts to change. Some changes are:

1. Resetting certain parts of the form.
2. Auto-filling certain parts of the form (e.g. for certain credit card we automatically offer address saved from past transactions)
3. rerun validity check of different parts (e.g. we only ship to this address for purchases of 100$ or more)

As far as I understand in React parent should not call functions on children (through ref) but rather declare state, which flows to the children through props. However, all of the changes mentioned are just initial state, and can be immediately overridden by user input.

My options as far as I understand are:

1. imperatively pass state to children. This could be done through ref, or through a prop "initial/override value". Either way I'm manually passing state, rather than having one single source of truth.
2. Make my children forms "dumb" and receive all form values from parent. This seems impractical (as far as I can tell) because I would have to pass every single input value up and receive all of them as props.

   3. Similar to 2, store the state in Redux. I would still have to store every single value of the form in the store, which is cumbersome It also seems to be discouraged by the React community.
   4. Give up on dividing the form into sub-components. I only have one source of truth (component state) Honestly that currently seems like the best solution.

How would you do it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The most appropriate solution given how complicated this can become is to have one centralized state object that is external to React entirely. The form elements should be as dumb as possible and get told what to show and changes should trigger callbacks leading to the main state object. This is not very common design for react applications but with forms it has many benefits over the already established patterns.